# Produce simple outline of complex polygon

Tags: qgis

I have a raster layer that I have converted to a polygon. I have then performed a calculation on the cell values. I have a categorised map of the output and want to be able to show a rough outline of one of the particular categories.

Here's a snippet of the categories map.

[image]

If we take the blue as an example. I want to produce an outline that is similar to this (made in PowerPoint):

[image]

Any suggestions as to a good way to do this?

Comment: How about concave hull ? https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#concave-hull-alpha-shapes

Comment: If that does not work you can buffer with a positive distance, dissolve, buffer with the same distance but negative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Concave Hull (alpha shapes)** is a pretty good approach, as suggested by J. Monticolo.

You will need to convert the lines to points first - **Points along geometry** will do this, with a Distance appropriate to the scale of your map. I used 1500m for an area that's around 170km E to W.

For **Concave Hull (alpha shapes)**, the Threshold option will determine how "wiggly" the hull is. You can see a range of values below from 0.1 (Yellow) to 0.2 (Green) to 0.3 (Blue).

[image]

If you subsequently want to smooth the sharp corners, you can use Smooth or Buffer, depending on what result you are after.